# VS2013 azure emulator worker run debug

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging, azure-worker-roles

Can't launch the azure emulator in debug mode. (vs2013 windows8)

Steps for scratch:

1. New project : Azure cloud Service
2. Add WorkerRole
3. F5 (run)

[image]

In step 3, If I press ctrl+f5 (run without debug) instead f5 (run) every things is ok, but can't use the remote debugger...

Any idea ?

Comment: did you really read the error message before posting it here? In 100% of the cases I worked on - it was FireWall issue. Remote Debugger requires specific outgoing ports, which not every sys-admin loves. All the articles you read on azure Remote Debugging suggest that you are already familiar with Remote Debugging in general. If you are not, then first read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0d7tte4.aspx then also read carefully: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683670.aspx It clearly shows what outgoing port are required.

Comment: @astaykov Yes I read the error message so many times and find nothing. So that why I searched a bit larger. But now I know that remote management and remote debugging are not linked. To try to found the problem I try to remote debug in local with azure emulator after lunch msvsmon and I get the same error... What should I check ?

Comment: @astaykov as MVP, I'm sure that your are pretty busy, but I don't find any solution... Following your first comment, I checked 2 links you gave me and I simplify the question. Because even in local (azure emulator) I can't make debugger works.. So i think that I should start resolve local first ;) So in local I switch off the fire wall, reinstall vs2013 community, azure sdk 2.5, try admin run as admin.. Could you give me more advices ? thx

Comment: and when you hit F5 you get the error that debugger cannot attach to process?

Comment: @astaykov I get exactly the error message in the picture in the  question (see above).

Comment: this is great but I don't speak french!

Comment: @astaykov arf shame on me..!! Picture edited :)

Comment: @astaykov I swith off firewall(software, windows firewall) client side and server side but nothing on physical firewall. Should I do something in the firewall on my box ? Should I do something on azure ?

Comment: @astaykov since begining you were right. Zone alarm my firewall... turned it off was not enough. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG so simple... I was my firewall. Zone alarm. I turned it off but IT'S WAS NOT enough. I add to unistall it! You can add rules instead of course. DOn't trust off zone alarm ;)